# How to subscribe to particular partition and read from custom offset in Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

I have a use case, where multiple tables are published to same topic but different partitions. I want to read from specific partition alone and from a custom offset.

```
 val data = sql.readStream.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "servers")
      .option("assign", {"TEST1":[0]})
      .option("startingOffsets",""" {"TEST1":{"0":172260244}} """)
      .option("endingOffsets",""" {"TEST1":{"0":-1}} """)
      .load()
```

So, when I am subscribing to it I am getting the following error. The topic name is being converted to lower case automatically.

```
WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource  - Error in attempt 1 getting Kafka offsets: 
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: If startingOffsets contains specific offsets, you must specify all TopicPartitions.
Use -1 for latest, -2 for earliest, if you don't care.
Specified: Set(test1-0) Assigned: Set(TEST1-0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue. Its a bug with Spark libraries upgrading to later versions fixed the issue.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19853